# Use front camera with built in camera app

Tags: android, camera

In my app, I'm using the built-in camera app to take pictures.
The thing is that this interface has a button to change camera ( to front) and when I take a picture with front picture, it is not working anymore.

So, Is there a way to take picture fromt front camera with built-in camera app.
If it is not posible, is there a way to remove the icon from built in app???

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Is this a programming question?

Comment: Well, I need to code it... but my code is not helping in this case, and I found nothing in google stackoverflow... what is your suggestion?

Comment: No, there's no way to change how the built in app works.  Especially since the camera app may be different on every device, not all use Google's default.  If you need that much control, its fairly easy to roll your own.

Comment: Ok so there is nothing I can do with built in so that front camera works???